# WHERE clause in SQL ignoring OR

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that is calculating the number of documents I have that are not in complete (1000) or canceled (1100). When I have just one of those conditionals it counts the number correctly but once I add the or, it simply grabs everything ignoring any of the logic.  There must be some fundamental thing i'm missing with SQL here

```
    SELECT 
       [PartnerCoId] as DisplayID
      ,[PartnerCompanyName] as DisplayName
      ,Count(*) as DocumentTotal
  FROM vwDocuments 
  where coid = @inputCoid and DocumentType = 'order' 
  and Status <> 1100 
  and PartnerCoId <> @inputCoid
  group by 
        [PartnerCoId]
       ,[PartnerCompanyName]
union all
SELECT [CoId] as DisplayID
      ,[CompanyName] as DisplayName      
      ,Count(*) as DocumentTotal
  FROM vwDocuments 
  where PartnerCoId = @inputCoid and DocumentType = 'order' 
  and Status <> 1100 
  and CoId <> @inputCoid
  group by [CoId]
      ,[CompanyName]            
    order by [DisplayName]
```

This will return the number of documents not in canceled status. If I change the 1100 to 1000 it returns the number of documents not in complete status. Once I update the query to:

```
and (Status <> 1100 or Status <> 1000)
```

It breaks the logic.

Thoughts?  I have tried quite a number of different combinations of query logic and cannot straighten this out.

Comment: Did you try changing it to an AND? If you want everything not equal to both of those it should be AND.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than wrestle with boolean logic, use `not in`:

```
and Status not in (1100, 1000)
```

It's easier to read and understand, because it's practically English, and because it's all in one statement you don't need brackets around it either.

Comment: This is a very elegant way to do it, thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you want everything where `Status` is neither `1100` nor `1000`.

If so, then you need this:

```
and (Status <> 1100 and Status <> 1000)
```

If you use `or`, then a `Status` of `1100` will pass the test because it is `<> 1000`.

Comment: Yes it is going to be that kind of day, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic may be a little bit off. Saying (NOT complete or NOT cancelled) will return all of your documents because all rows will fit this criteria.

Take a document with status of 1100. This will be returned in the query because it evaluates to TRUE on half of the OR statement.

Try replacing that line with

```
AND Status NOT IN (1000,1100)
```

This should return only documents that are neither completed or cancelled. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify and think about your logic.

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1;

IF (@i <> 1 OR @i <> 2)
  PRINT 'true';
ELSE
  PRINT 'false';
```

Can you provide a value for `@i` that generates `false`? I can't think of one. Think about it:

- if `@i = 1`, then `@i <> 1` is false, but `@i <> 2` is true. Since only one of these conditions has to be true for the whole condition to be true, the result is true.
- if `@i = 2`, then `@i <> 1` is true, but `@i <> 2` is false. Since only one of these conditions has to be true for the whole condition to be true, the result is true.
- if `@i` is any other value outside of `1` and `2`, then both conditions are true.

As the other answers demonstrate, the way to fix this is to change `OR` to `AND`, or use `NOT IN` (though I like `NOT IN` less because when you are checking a column, and the column is `NULL`able, [the results surprise and confuse most people](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) - and I prefer to program consistently instead of having to be aware of the cases where something works and the cases where it really, really doesn't).